# Objects not appearing when I render my model

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects

Objects do not appear when I render my model in blender 2.71. All objects are set to appear when rendered. Pressing W and clicking Clear all Restrict Render doesn't work, either. I only get a background when I render.

Edit: There are no strips in the VSE and all correct layers are set to view when rendered.

[Blend file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/f5y51klyo9otdd1/Cycles_render_room_in_aero_apartments_elevator_lobby.blend](http://www.mediafire.com/download/f5y51klyo9otdd1/Cycles_render_room_in_aero_apartments_elevator_lobby.blend)

Comment: Make sure the correct layers are specified in your render layer(s) and that you have no interfering strips in the VSE. If those don't solve it, is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have light in your scene.

The hemi lamp in the middle of the room won't work, as cycles doesn't support hemi lamps yet. [It will be treated like a sun lamp](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Lamps).

[Sun lamps](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Lamps#Sun_Lamp) provide a uniform amount light from infinitely far away in a specific direction with no falloff. Because of this, the position of the lamp doesn't have any effect.
Since the room is completely closed and light has no way to get in from outside, everything renders as black.

If you change the lamp to a [point lamp](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Lamps#Point_Lamp) and increase the strength to something like 1000, you get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This fixed the black. Now I can see my first four modeled blender elevators when I render an image. Yaaaaayyyy.

Comment: @Cyborggeffien If this answer satisfactorily answered your question, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it. :)