# UV texture not visible in render

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

**PLEASE READ THE QUESTION, DO NOT MARK AS DUPLICATE**

I have looked at this [Render not showing UV texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/render-not-showing-uv-texture)

and this:
[Texture view works, but render is without texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20845/texture-view-works-but-render-is-without-texture)

But I cannot find what is wrong

The textures show up in texture view just fine:
[image: capture 1]
But not in render view:
[image: capture 2]
It's just black

I've followed tutorials, created a material and then a texture, assigned an image and set coordinates to UV, selected map. Still not working.

Here is the blend:
http://pasteall.org/blend/35260

Comment: You need a light, probably a Sun Lamp

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/why-does-my-object-appear-flat-when-rendering/26214#26214

Comment: It looks like you do not have any lights.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19489/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15891/599